# Specify the inheritance of location, rotation, scale when parenting objects

Tags: animation

I have these two objects A and B.
I want A to follow B but only A's location not rotation.

Everytime I use the parenting method, child object always follows every 
detail with parent object.

This A object rotates but I want B not to rotate, just follow A's location.
How is it possible? Should I use other method? not parenting one?

Comment: Use drivers for that.

Comment: To use drivers (properly)  would entail adding three drivers for each x, y and z component of location targeted to same of target object. Any change, eg target would involve editing three drivers. Recommend a constraint as below.

Answer (score 2):

[**Copy Location Constraint**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/constraints/transform/copy_location.html)

Blender has a copy location, rotation and scale constraint, as well as a copy transform constraint (*ie* copy all three_)  Adding all of location, rotation and scale, or copy transform with influence 1 and using world space is the equivalent of parenting.

For question example consider adding just  a copy location constraint on A targeting B

[image]
*Example default Cube at location of default Camera. With offset unchecked is at exact global location. With it checked will behave similarly to a child, and be offset from parent based on its location*

Leaving above the same: If we add another copy location constraint, targeting the Light, with influence 1, the cube will be at location of Light. With influence 0.5 will be half way between Camera and Light.

Answer (score 1):

For fully controllable parenting, you can use the [Child Of](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/constraints/relationship/child_of.html#child-of-constraint) constraint, which allows you to select which transforms, and which axes of those transforms, the constrained child object inherits from the target parent object.

You can also use the Influence value of the constraint to hand the child from one parent to another.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are a form of parenting selected properties (location, rotation, scale) with **one** variable controlling **just one** property. In your case you add drivers to location.

Drivers also allow more control, with **expressions**, than simple constraints. [See an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwml0p6xroslcj7/Drivers_AEx.avi?dl=0)